# Не понимаю артикль img, а точнее border| html

Tags: html

вообще не понимаю артикль img, не понимаю как делать "рамку", но знаю что при этом используется border.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Солныщко</title>
  <meta cherset="utf-8" <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="green">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>кто то думает что солнце выглдит так:</h1>
  <p>
    <img src="https://productcenter.ru/images/456756-solnyshko-540x480.jpg" alt="Солныщко" width="196" height="196" border: 2px solid #ff0000>
  </p>

  <h2>но на самом деле...</h2>
  <p>
    <img src="https://aboutspacejornal.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/sun1-1024x9101.jpg" alt="солнце" width="196" height="196" border: 2px solid #ff0000>
  </p>
  <p> ну вот это пока все..</p>
</body>

</html>
```

объясните проблему, т.к на сторонних сайтах не нашел, хотя может и плохо искал

(извиняюсь за возможно тупой вопрос)

Comment: style="border: 2px solid #ff0000"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Забыли написать **style=""**. Цвет и пиксели укажите которые вам нужно

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Солныщко</title>
  <meta cherset="utf-8" <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="green">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>кто то думает что солнце выглдит так:</h1>
  <p>
    <img src="https://productcenter.ru/images/456756-solnyshko-540x480.jpg" alt="Солныщко" width="196" height="196" border: 2px solid #ff0000>
  </p>

  <h2>но на самом деле...</h2>
  <p>
    <img src="https://aboutspacejornal.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/sun1-1024x9101.jpg" alt="солнце" width="196" height="196" style="border: 10px solid red">
  </p>
  <p> ну вот это пока все..</p>
</body>

</html>
```